# Underfull \hbox warning with \RaggedLeft

Tags: captions, ragged2e

I use the `mcaption` package to place the captions in the margin column. With `\RaggedOuter` I align them properly on even and odd pages, respectively. Only on even pages, I tend to get underfull \hbox warnings. This happens with `\RaggedLeft`, but not with `\raggedleft`. Of course, I rely on the improved version \RaggedLeft because the original one does not even hyphenate particular words when I include `\-` hints.

Here is my example code:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt, paper=a4, DIV=classic]{scrbook}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\KOMAoption{headinclude}{false}
\KOMAoption{footinclude}{false}
\KOMAoption{mpinclude}{true}
\recalctypearea
\setlength{\marginparsep}{2em}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{10em}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[top]{mcaption}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\let\RaggedOuter\RaggedRight
\newcommand{\setOddEvenPageLayout}{\ifthispageodd%
  {\let\RaggedOuter\RaggedRight}{\let\RaggedOuter\RaggedLeft}}

\addtokomafont{caption}{\RaggedOuter\small}
\setkomafont{captionlabel}{\sffamily\bfseries}
\setcapindent*{0pt}
\renewcommand{\captionformat}{}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Margin captions}

\section{Odd Page}

\blindtext

\begin{table}[h]
\setOddEvenPageLayout
\begin{margincap}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
Test & Test & Test \\
\midrule
Wer & das & liest \\
ist & selbst & schuld \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Überblick über die Kontrollstrukturen}
\end{margincap}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\clearpage

\section{Even page}

\blindtext

\begin{table}[h]
\setOddEvenPageLayout
\begin{margincap}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\toprule
Test & Test & Test \\
\midrule
Wer & das & liest \\
ist & selbst & schuld \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\caption{Überblick über die Kontrollstrukturen}
\end{margincap}
\end{table}

\blindtext

\end{document}
```

What can the the reason for the strange behaviour that only `\RaggedLeft`, but not `\RaggedRight` and not `\raggedleft` produce the warning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see the same with a simpler example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

{\RaggedRight

abc

}

{\RaggedLeft

abc

}


\end{document}
```

with `\RaggedRight` the last line of a paragraph gets `\pafillskip` at the right hand side, but `\RaggedLeft` all lines including the last only get restricted stretch space.

Comment: That means the underfull \hbox warning does not really tell me something. Is there any trick or hack to suppress it?

Comment: @Matthias not easily. In captions, as they are in a box not on the main vertical list as in my example, you could in theory set it with `\parfillskip` set to the default `\fill` glue then the warning would go but the last line of  the paragraph would always go flush left then you could use `\lastbox` to dis-assemble the box and re-position the last line flush right, but it's not easy and rather fragile and might clash with other macros eg color would make it hard, and ignoring the warning in this case is certainly easier.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I would have taken ages to search for a solution since I hate warnings almost as much as errors. But if you tell me to give up I will certainly do so ...

Comment: @Matthias you could add `\hbadness=10000` to your caption code which locally turns off the badness warning just for that paragraph.

Comment: That's a nice idea. Works perfectly.